# Key Error while appending data into dictionary of list in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, keyerror

I am trying to create a dictionary where the key values are stored in a list like this :

```
data={
    "key_value":["h1","h2","h3"],
    "key_value2":["h11","h21","h31"],
}
```

While adding elements to this list of dicts, I am using this function :

```
data[book_name].append(highlight)
```

But this gives me a key error `KeyError: 'Key_value '`
Why is this happening?

Comment: Looks like there's a space at the end of `'Key_value '`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Also, your example has `key_value` which is lowercase.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes compiler is showing a space after the string. That is intentional

Comment: @JohnGordon no actual compiler message is : KeyError: 'The 4-Hour Work Week '.

Comment: "just make this work" fix = `data.setdefault(book_name, []).append(highlight)`

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please [edit] the question with further details, rather than posting follow up comments which contradict with the original question.

Comment: You are getting that error because `data[book_name]` does not exist.

Comment: @python_user this works thanks! I came from C++, that's why I didn't know you had to set a default value for key.

Comment: Try this out `data['key_value'].append('highlight')`. You're getting the error may be because `data[book_name]` doesn't exist and `key_value` should be lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question stands `data.setdefault(book_name, []).append(highlight)` can be used. If the key is not present it will create a new key with an empty list as value, else you will get the list for the existing key to which you can append.

Note : If you have keys that have trailing white spaces this can lead to "unexpected" behavior. eg : `data[' key']` vs `data['key ']`. You can use something like `data.setdefault(book_name.strip(), []).append(highlight)`  to overcome this.

Suggested Reading :[collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring because you put a space in `data['key_value ']`. It should be like this: `data['key_value']`.

When you try to access any key of dictionary, make sure the key is in same way as in your dictionary.

For eg, your dictionary is:

```
data={
    'key1': ['val1','val2']
}
```

If you are trying to access key of dictionary, it should be `data['key1']`, not `data[' key1']` or `data['key1 ']` or `data[' key1 ']`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is no key in your dictionary called book_list.  You can append to a value_list for an existing key, like your "key_value2", like this:

```
data={"key_value":["h1","h2","h3"], "key_value2":["h11","h21","h31"]}
data["key_value2"].append("highlight")
print(data)
#prints: {'key_value': ['h1', 'h2', 'h3'], 'key_value2': ['h11', 'h21', 'h31', 'highlight']}
```

If you want to create an entirely new key_value pair in your dictionary and then append more values to the value list, you can do it like this:

```
#create a new key, the value for which is a list:
data["book_names"] = ["highlight"]

#append another value to the value list for existing key:
data['book_names'].append("lowlights")

#Output:
#data after first operation: {'key_value': ['h1', 'h2', 'h3'], 'key_value2': ['h11', 'h21', 'h31'], 'book_names': ['highlight']}
#data after second operation: {'key_value': ['h1', 'h2', 'h3'], 'key_value2': ['h11', 'h21', 'h31'], 'book_names': ['highlight', 'lowlights']}
```